# Creating a Dynamic Chart using MScharts in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am new to C# programming, but I am trying to create an application to display data I send it from a microcontroller. I currently am just reading in the data and storing it in a CSV file.  I have also created a function to parse the file and load the stored data into a data table.

I would like to populate a graph using the data table. I have searched through Google and looked through the WinSamples provided by Microsoft. I haven't been able to understand any of the code snippets enough to get anything started.

The stored data is voltage measurements and temperature measurements from battery cells. The CSV file has "Cell_*" as the column header. The asterisk is the cell number. Then, the voltage values and temperature values are listed in the first two rows starting at column 0.

I want to populate a bar graph with the cells on the x-axis and the voltages and temps on the y-axis. The best I can come up with is:

```
    chart1.DataSource = measuredData.dt;

    // Set series members names for the X and Y values
    chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Cell_1";
    chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Cell_2";
    chart1.DataBind();
```

This gives me data from the table, but how do I set it use the rows as the y-values and to read the cell names for the x-values?  Also, is it possible to create the number of series at run-time?

```
Cell_1 | Cell_2 | Cell_3
1.32   | 1.45   | 2.00
```

Comment: Not sure if i get the data structure, can show a few rows as in how your data is available

Comment: Cell_1 | Cell_2  | Cell_3
 1.32  | 1.45    | 2.00

Comment: Not sure, how to show it here but this is better I guess: Row 1: Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell3 //Row 2: 1.32  |  2.00 | 3.40